# True value from SQL being brought into listbox as -1

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-word

Never run into this before. I'm bringing some column values into a listbox from SQL server using VBA. One of the columns, Exception, is a boolean so it's value in SQL is either 0 or 1. However, when I'm loading the results into the listbox in my VBA form it's being displayed as -1. I've attached my code below. Any insights would be great.

```
Sub Getattendhistory()
database_connect
Dim SQLstr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Counter As Long
Dim list As Object
Set list = AttendHistory.Results
SQLstr = "select [ID],[createddate],[notseatedreason],[exception],[exceptionreason] from dbo.[attendancehistory] where [agentname] = '" & SearchForm.Results.Text & "'"
rs.Open SQLstr, appconn, adOpenStatic
If (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
MsgBox "No Attendance History.Contact Command Center"
Exit Sub
End If
With list
Counter = 0
Do Until rs.EOF
    .AddItem
    .list(Counter, 0) = rs![ID]
    .list(Counter, 1) = rs![CreatedDate]
    If IsNull(rs![NotSeatedReason]) Then .list(Counter, 2) = "Seated"
    If Not IsNull(rs![NotSeatedReason]) Then .list(Counter, 2) = rs![NotSeatedReason]
    If IsNull(rs![Exception]) Then .list(Counter, 3) = ""
    If Not IsNull(rs![Exception]) Then .list(Counter, 3) = rs![Exception]
    If IsNull(rs![Exceptionreason]) Then .list(Counter, 4) = "N/A"
    If Not IsNull(rs![Exceptionreason]) Then .list(Counter, 4) = rs![Exceptionreason]
Counter = Counter + 1
rs.MoveNext
Loop
End With
rs.Close
database_Disconnect
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Before you write another line of code you desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Building up a string like that is wide open to sql injection. Fix this before [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) comes to visit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in VBA (and VB in general) True is stored as -1 and false as 0.  Just because SQL Server represents True as 1 and False as 0, what's actually being returned in the record set is Boolean True or Boolean False.   So when you display Exception, True is being represented as -1.  What you probably want to do is conditionally display the string "True" or "False" depending on the Boolean value.

Here's a link to the VB Language Reference.  This is for VB.Net, but the same value and reasons holds true for VB6 and VBA as well.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/boolean-data-type